# How do I Generate Clones In Python?

Tags: python, clone, turtle-graphics

I am making a simplified version of Space Invaders and I am trying to make the bullets shot from the player's character. I have made a turtle for the character (main_ship) and a turtle for the bullet (bullet). How can I clone the bullet (for the purpose of shooting them)? This is my code for the bullet:

```
`bullet = turtle.Turtle()
bullet.speed(0)
bullet.shape("circle")
bullet.color("red")
bullet.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.5, stretch_len=0.5)
bullet.penup()
bullet.goto(main_ship.xcor(), main_ship.ycor())
bullet.hideturtle()`
```

I have not tried anything yet as I cannot find anything explaining how.

Comment: can you create a method containing the logic you've posted and then just call it to create a new bullet each time?

Comment: Are you familiar with lists? Try creating a list named `bullets`, which you append Turtle instances to as your character fires them.

Comment: Have you looked into copy/deepcopy? https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your bullets are turtles, have you looked at turtle's own `clone()` method:

```
Help on function clone in module turtle:

clone()

    No argument.

    Create and return a clone of the turtle with same position, heading
    and turtle properties.

    Example (for a Turtle instance named mick):
    mick = Turtle()
    joe = mick.clone()
```

Since turtles are effectively global entities, and never garbage collected, I recommend you not *waste* bullets but rather keep a pool (`list`) of available ones and that you pull from as needed and add back to when a bullet is no longer active.  Only clone additional bullets, from a dedicated prototype, when the pool is empty.